# Add block from local.xml in Magento

Tags: magento

I need to add a custom block on a page. Doesn't really matter where. For this example, I want it on *customer/account/*

So, looking on *customer.xml* I see this path:

```
   <customer_account_index translate="label">
       [code]
       <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
           [code]
       </reference name="my.account.wrapper">
   </customer_account_index>
```

Following this example here is my code in *local.xml*

```
    <customer_account_index>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="core/template" 
           name="customer_groupsprogressbar"          
           template="customer/groupsprogressbar.phtml" />
    </reference>
    </customer_account_index>
```

Something is wrong, because it doesn't appear. If I add that block in *customer.xml* instead all works fine.

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Which local.xml are you talking about? Can you give the complete path to the file?

Comment: local.xml from template. app/design/frontend/default/THEME/layout/layout.xml

Comment: Check System->configuration->Design, what you you have in package? Should be default.

Comment: moreover does your shop has "THEME" theme?

Comment: yes, it is default. I just used THEME for exemplication, I'm using my theme name, not 'THEME'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block 
            type="core/text_list" 
            name="customer_groupsprogressbar"          
            template="customer/groupsprogressbar.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

Or

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block 
            type="core/template" 
            name="customer_groupsprogressbar"          
            template="customer/groupsprogressbar.phtml" output="toHtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

OR
in my.account.wrapper template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_groupsprogressbar'); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry but i want to know do we need to place 'as' in <block>?

Comment: This is no necessary. as is alias. Means if  you have <block name="a_b" as="a.b" ... /> then you can call it like this $this->getChildHtml('a_b') or $this->getChildHtml('a.b')

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov  first and second are not working.
Third option could be working but is not what I need. I want this block in xml file only to be able to move wherever I want without modifying any template file.

Comment: Impossible, they both should work. Means they are not loaded at all. Check the third option please.

Comment: Damn, I'm so stupid. And blind apparently.. In fact the block was rendered just fine. But because layout.xml had not 'before' or 'after' instruction was all the way down but when called in customer.xml it was on top. So I was expecting to see on top too.
So sorry guys and thank you for your effort.